# rsyncd daemon - how to minimize logged information?

Tags: backup, nas, rsync, logging, synology

I backup my synology NAS to a linux Debian server that runs rsyncd daemon. A typical backup session will write hundreds of thousands useless messages (sample below) to the daemon log file.

**Q:** How can I configure rsyncd on Debian so that only error and warning and authorization messages are sent to the log file and nothing else?

**Constraint:** Synology backup client is a closed system that I have zero control over. All configuration changes must occur on the Debian server.

**Current rsyncd.conf file**

```
port = 873
max verbosity = 0

[NAS]
path = /media/e230a109-1a8b-bd46-81fc8-304c5d8fe401a/./
uid = nobody
gid = users
list = yes
read only = no
write only = no
use chroot = yes
hosts allow = 192.168.0.100
hosts deny = ALL
lock file = /var/lock/rsyncd-NAS
```

**Sample of useless log entries**

```
Tue Mar 24 07:54:34 2015    building file list
Tue Mar 24 07:54:34 2015    rsync on NAS/nas_0032110CDF4A/@app/_Syno_NetShareArchive.db from nas.local (192.168.0.100)
Tue Mar 24 07:54:34 2015    connect from nas.local (192.168.0.100)
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    sent 87 bytes received 42 bytes total size 2048
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    building file list
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    rsync on NAS/nas_0032110CDF4A/@app/_Syno_NetShareArchive.db from nas.local (192.168.0.100)
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    connect from nas.local (192.168.0.100)
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    sent 42 bytes received 56 bytes total size 0
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    receiving file list
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    rsync to NAS/nas_0032110CDF4A/ from nas.local (192.168.0.100)
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    connect from nas.local (192.168.0.100)
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    sent 54 bytes received 2146 bytes total size 2048
Tue Mar 24 07:54:33 2015    receiving file list

and so on...
```

Comment: It looks like an rsync session is started *for every single file*. Those messages you show should only be shown once during a backup, not repeated for every file. The backup script is clearly written by someone who has very little understanding of how rsync works. You could send all messages to /dev/null with `log file = /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks [wurtel](http://superuser.com/users/365297/wurtel), I had actually already applied /dev/null as a temporary work-around. However, /dev/null eliminates all messages, including errors/warnings/authentication, which I want to keep. But from your analysis it sounds like there isn't much that I can do to fix this unless I can convince Synology to change their implementation.

Comment: As far as I can see, that's correct.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Doing individual rsync transfers per file can be faster in large directories, but the log volume is about 3 times as high.

Comment: No, I never found a real solution, `logfile = /dev/null` is just a mitigation strategy.